# Using calculus to show that $f_n(x)=x^n$ is not Cauchy in $C^0[0,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

As the title says, I need to prove "using calculus" that the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=x^n$ is not Cauchy in $C^0[0,1]$.

The thing that came to my mind is to use the $L_1$ or $L_2$ norm since there are some integral calculations in it and thus it'd be "using calculus." But then I saw it'd prove the opposite in that the given sequence IS Cauchy. At this point I think only using the max(infinity) norm would give me the proof. But would that be "using calculus?"

Comment: What does to be Cauchy for a sequence of functions mean ?

Comment: Much the same problem was asked earlier [in this Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1265504/is-the-sequence-of-functions-f-nx-xn-cauchy-in-c0-1-is-it-cauchy).  Note especially the difference between the sequences of functions under the $L_2$-norm and the (max) $L_\infty$-norm.  One suspects that the latter was intended by your original assignment because the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ is complete in that norm (and not in $L_1$ or $L_2$).

Comment: Your question is contradictory to me, because with $L^2$-norm this sequence *is* Cauchy, but does *not* converge. Whereas with $L^\infty$-norm (the max-norm) it is *not* Cauchy. you have to specify the norm on the space

Comment: @BernhardListing: What norm or metric is being considered on $C^0[0,1]$?

Comment: @Physor: It does converge with $L^2$-norm, since $\Vert f_n\Vert_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\to0$, so it converges to the zero function.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos thanks for the note

Comment: @BernhardListing: If you have the uniform norm in mind, then Ted's solution does the trick: $\|f_n-f_{2n}\|_u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible solution, which I leave you to complete. What is the maximum value of $f_n-f_{2n}$?

Comment: so to get the max value, do you take the first derivative of it (setting it to be $0$)? and the max value, does it turn out to be $\frac{n(n-1)}{(2n-1)^2}$? here is this value supposed to be something that didn't depend on $n$?

Comment: Yes, find the critical point. But something went wrong. Check your algebra.

Comment: thanks, i got it